# Workflow doesn't start when an item is created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions, office-365

I have a document library where items are copied with a workflow from another library. I set a workflow in this library that is suposed to start when an item is added but it only starts when the creator of the item (although the item is copied by a workflow it keeps the created by colum) has edit permissions. If the user doesn't have those permissions the workflow doesn't start.

I don't want to give edit permissions to those user but I need the workflow to start, is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

you can start another workflow from current workflow using REST. Below is example.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2/

please add all the URL in workflow in App Step. below is example for configuring app step.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx